Make an API call when the user closes tab or window (Vue)
I am creating a multiplayer game in Vue. Players can create games which gets on a waiting list which other players can then press to join the 2 person game.
I want to detect when a user closes the window or the browser and then remove the user from this waiting list since they are no longer able to start a game. I have this waiting list of games in a mongodb schema, and I remove them with the call to my express server:
router.delete("/waiting/remove/user/:userId", async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;
  
    try {
      const deletedGames = await WaitingGame.deleteMany({ userId });
  
      if (deletedGames .deletedCount > 0) {
        io.emit("waitingListUpdate");
  
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "All waiting games for the user removed successfully.",
        });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "No waiting games found for the user, but request was successful.",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to remove waiting games." });
    }
  });

Can I just call this API in window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleBeforeUnload);? I heard it is not 100% reliable that it can make the call since it is time limit. I need to be 100% it removes all the games from this list.
I also read somewhere that I can do like this:
handleBeforeUnload(event) {
      const userId = "123";
      const url = `/waiting/remove/user/${userId}`;
      const data = new Blob([], { type: 'application/json' }); 
      navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
    }

What exactly do sendBeacon do and will it ensure that the things is sent to my API? Or do I need to make anything else?

you're using sockets right?  you should combine beforeunload with periodic socket heartbeats to determine if the user is still connected, and if not, delete them server-side.

Did you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API ? It can ensure as sure as this can be done. It's restricted to POST, so it won't work with DELETE. beforeunload is as reliable as it can be too. "since it is time limit" - do you mean that the request is async? This is the reason to use a beacon and not just  regular request. fetch+keepalive can do this too but it has less support and so less reliable
